# Deployable using mgwt and gwt-phonegap

Tags: gwt, cordova

I have just setup a project/run the gwt project(Eclipse) by looking into the wiki. Even I know about the standalone phonegap project build.But I don't understand how to create APK/IPA/windows deployable by using gwt-phonegap. Is there any tutorial available for explaining this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an APK is a different history. You should create an Android project and include the compiled gwt and mgwt project into them (folder assets/www).

That urls might be useful:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=it
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=it
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Comment: Thanks. after putting compiled gwt code inside phone_gap../assets/www, I build it again for android, then my test hello project worked.